# Prove $\sup(A^2) = (\sup(A))^2$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, problem-solving, supremum-and-infimum, theorem-provers

So we let A be non empty set of R that’s bounded. Define $A^2=\{a^2\mid a \in A\}.$ How do we prove that the $\sup(A^2) = (\sup(A))^2.$ I've been approaching this by showing that $(\sup A)^2$ is an upper bound of $A^2$ and then showing that it's the least among the set of upper bounds. That is to say, I've been approaching it from the definition of $\sup A^2.$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've been approaching this by showing that (supA)^2 is an upper bound of A^2 and then showing that it's the least among the set of upper bounds. That is to say, I've been approaching it from the definition of supA^2.

Comment: It's not true, unless $\sup A\geq -\inf A.$

Comment: How do I prove that ?

Comment: How do you prove something which isn't true? If you want to change your question, change it. As a counterexample, $A=\{-2,1\}$ then $A^2=\{1,4\}$ and $\sup A=1, \sup(A^2)=4.$

Comment: @LizaZee to show it's false you just need to find a counter example. When it involves squaring it's often useful to look at negative numbers and positive numbers separately since they each cover the positive reals.

Comment: I just don’t know how to start

Comment: Did the problem state that $A$ is a nonempty, bounded set of *positive* numbers? (You seem not to be reading or thinking about comments.)

Comment: All the information you need is in the comments.

Comment: The correct version is that if $f(x)$ is an increasing function, then $\sup\{f(A)\}=f(\sup A)$ where $f(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $A$ is a bounded set of nonnegative real numbers.
Let us prove that $\sup(A^2) = (\sup(A))^2$.

First we prove $\sup(A^2) \leq (\sup(A))^2$.
If $a \in A$ then we have $0 \leq a \leq \sup(A)$. Since the square fonction is increasing on nonnegative numbers, this yields $0 \leq a^{2} \leq (\sup(A))^{2}$, for any $a \in A$.
Hence $\sup(A^2) \leq (\sup(A))^2$.

Now we prove $\sup(A^2) \geq (\sup(A))^2$.
Let $a \in A$. We have $a^{2} \leq \sup(A^{2})$. By taking the root, since everything is nonnegative, we get $a \leq \sqrt{\sup(A^{2})}$. Since this is true for any
$a \in A$, we get $\sup(A) \leq \sqrt{\sup(A^{2})}$. Since this is nonnegative and the square function is increasing on nonnegative numbers, we get $(\sup(A))^{2} \leq \sup(A^{2})$.